# Can I force the browser to render out the DOM changes before continuing javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser

I am populating a table with about 500 rows, which takes the browser a few seconds to render, while it appears frozen. This is why I want to display a message asking for the user's patience:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '{{ search_url }}',
  success: function (response) {
    $('#progress').text('Rendering results, please wait...');
    clear_table();
    populate_table(response);
  }
});
```

The message isn't displayed - apparently the browser (tested in Chrome 23) buffers all the DOM changes and renders them all in a single go.

As a workaround I found that when I delay populating the table until execution is back to the event loop the message is actually displayed:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '{{ search_url }}',
  success: function (response) {
    $('#progress').text('Rendering results, please wait...');
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      clear_table();
      populate_table(response);
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

I wonder if this method will always work or if there is a better technique for this case.

Comment: message should trigger before ajax call is started, not in the success callback

Comment: Yes, your `setTimeout` would be the appropriate solution, and it will always work.

Comment: ...and also perhaps improving the performance of your `populate_table`. 500 rows isn't all that many, so it wouldn't seem like it should take too long to process.

Comment: Yes, seemed kind of strange to me, too. Well, it's jQuery and there's column width adjustment involved but I'll see if I can put together an isolated test case.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537578/populating-a-table-with-500-rows-takes-long-jquery-and-bootstrap-css / https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/se-andrekr/populating-table-slow/index.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because Javascript execution is single threaded. So until all your JS code is executed the browser will not do anything - in other words it will freeze. To prevent that I suggest you use the [jQuery Async plugin](http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php) (which is just a few lines of code) which will periodically give control back to the browser (by using `setTimeout`). This prevents the browser from freezing and will display the wait message without any problems.

Comment: Nice, since the populating is already an $.each, it's a like 20 character change. It uses the same technique as my workaround.

Comment: It's been a while ... But because I'm having a similar problem (Chrome 83 not updating a button's text/html during a $.each loop in my extension) I was wondering: why does it work in Firefox? Where can I learn more about the rendering strategy differences between all browsers?