# Populating a table with 500 rows takes long - jQuery and Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Inspired by the comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537096/can-i-force-the-browser-to-render-out-the-dom-changes-before-continuing-javascri) I put together [a testcase](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/se-andrekr/populating-table-slow/index.htm).

It's populating a table with 500 rows which takes about 15 seconds in Chrome 23 on my PC. Removing the Bootstrap CSS doesn't exactly make it instant but improves the time significantly.

The actual code for adding the rows is:

```
$.each(response, function (idx, row) {
  var new_row = $('#row_template').clone();
  new_row.removeAttr('id');
  $('td[data-name=col1]', new_row).text(row.col1);
  $('td[data-name=col2]', new_row).text(row.col2);
  $('td[data-name=col3]', new_row).text(row.col3);
  $('td[data-name=col4]', new_row).text(row.col4);
  $('td[data-name=col5]', new_row).text(row.col5);
  $('td[data-name=col6]', new_row).text(row.col6);
  $('td[data-name=col7]', new_row).text(row.col7);
  $('td[data-name=col8]', new_row).text(row.col8);
  $('td[data-name=col9]', new_row).text(row.col9);
  $('td[data-name=col10]', new_row).text(row.col10);
  new_row.insertBefore($('#row_template')).show();
});
```

The abolutely lowest execution time I would probably get by concatenating HTML and `getElementById().innerHTML`, but can I do any other obvious optimizations while still maintaining some ease of use (especially getting the row from the template)?

Comment: strange.. original test case only takes about 2 seconds in Firefox. Concatenation or using a template system to do the concatenating is a lot more performant though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only slow when you do it while the table is visible. If you hide it before and show it again after the changes it is quite fast:

```
$('#results').hide();

$.each(response, function (idx, row) {
  ...
});

$('#results').show();
```

Check out my solution here: http://smartk8.no-ip.org/stackoverflow/13537578.htm

Comment: I can sympathize with the browser... I also work slower when someone's watching. ;)

Comment: SmartK8 - this is indeed fast but you haven't actually answered the question, just linked to an answer. That won't do anyone else any good in the future when they click on the link and it doesn't point anywhere. Links are nice, code is required and so much better.

Comment: Yep, that's the jist of it. I tend to believe the JS is capable of independent work, and doesn't need to be looked over the shoulder all the time. :)

Comment: Kato: Thanks, I was already working on more elaborate answer. I was just giving preview answer quickly.

Comment: I did some testing. Actually it doesn't make any difference if we remove the `display: none` or keep the `.show()`. The important thing is that the table is hidden during the process. I edited the answer to make that clear, please see if you agree.

Comment: I guess it's possible. The layout has to be rearranged each time.

Comment: Ah yes this is a good plan and it's reminded me that  http://api.jquery.com/detach/ removes an element from page but retains the jQuery data so you can manipulate it then put it back which may be faster still.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add each row - it means redrawing 500 times. Add them to one string of html and add that to your page. example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLSy9/

```
<button id="addmany">Add one at a time</button>
<button id="addonce">Conact then add</button>
<table>
</table>​
```

jQ:

```
$('#addmany').on('click', function(){

    for (i=0; i<5000; i++)
    {
        var row=$('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');
        row.appendTo('table');
    }
});

$('#addonce').on('click', function(){
    rows='';
    for (i=0; i<5000; i++)
    {
        var row='<tr><td>test</td></tr>';
        rows=rows+row;
    }
    $(rows).appendTo('table');
});

​
```

Comment: Also +1 because with 0.1s this is even faster than SmartK8's solution, which takes 0.4s. It has ugly code and sacrifices the templating functionality, though.

Comment: In case someone's interested... a hybrid solution (getting the outerHTML of the edited elements, concatenating that and then inserting it) isn't faster than SmartK8's solution.